# Unique strings in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have following sample DataFrame `d` consisting of two columns 'col1' and 'col2'. I would like to find the list of unique names for the whole DataFrame d.

```
    d = {'col1':['Pat, Joseph', 
                 'Tony, Hoffman', 
                 'Miriam, Goodwin', 
                 'Roxanne, Padilla',
                 'Julie, Davis', 
                 'Muriel, Howell', 
                 'Salvador, Reese', 
                 'Kristopher, Mckenzie',
                 'Lucille, Thornton', 
                 'Brenda, Wilkerson'],

     'col2':['Kristopher, Mckenzie', 
             'Lucille, Thornton',
             'Pete, Fitzgerald; Cecelia, Bass; Julie, Davis', 
             'Muriel, Howell', 'Harriet, Phillips',
             'Belinda, Drake;David, Ford', 'Jared, Cummings;Joanna, Burns;Bob, Cunningham',
             'Keith, Hernandez;Pat, Joseph', 'Kristopher, Mckenzie', 'Lucille, Thornton']}

    df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

For column col1 i can get it done by using function unique().

```
df.col1.unique()
array(['Pat, Joseph', 'Tony, Hoffman', 'Miriam, Goodwin',
       'Roxanne, Padilla', 'Julie, Davis', 'Muriel, Howell',
       'Salvador, Reese', 'Kristopher, Mckenzie', 'Lucille, Thornton',
       'Brenda, Wilkerson'], dtype=object)
```

> ```
> len(df.col1) 10 # total number of rows
> len(df.col1.unique())  9 # total number of unique rows
> ```

For col2 some of the rows have multiple names separated by a semicolon. e.g. `'Pete, Fitzgerald; Cecelia, Bass; Julie, Davis'`.

How can I get the unique names from the col2 using vector operation? I am trying to avoid the for loop since the actual data set is large.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) by `;s\*` (regex - `;` with zero or more whitespaces) to `DataFrame`, then reshape by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for `Series` and last use `unique`:

```
print (df['col2'].str.split(';\s*', expand=True).stack().unique())
['Kristopher, Mckenzie' 'Lucille, Thornton' 'Pete, Fitzgerald'
 'Cecelia, Bass' 'Julie, Davis' 'Muriel, Howell' 'Harriet, Phillips'
 'Belinda, Drake' 'David, Ford' 'Jared, Cummings' 'Joanna, Burns'
 'Bob, Cunningham' 'Keith, Hernandez' 'Pat, Joseph']
```

Detail:

```
print (df['col2'].str.split(';\s*', expand=True))
                      0               1                2
0  Kristopher, Mckenzie            None             None
1     Lucille, Thornton            None             None
2      Pete, Fitzgerald   Cecelia, Bass     Julie, Davis
3        Muriel, Howell            None             None
4     Harriet, Phillips            None             None
5        Belinda, Drake     David, Ford             None
6       Jared, Cummings   Joanna, Burns  Bob, Cunningham
7      Keith, Hernandez     Pat, Joseph             None
8  Kristopher, Mckenzie            None             None
9     Lucille, Thornton            None             None

print (df['col2'].str.split(';\s*', expand=True).stack())
0  0    Kristopher, Mckenzie
1  0       Lucille, Thornton
2  0        Pete, Fitzgerald
   1           Cecelia, Bass
   2            Julie, Davis
3  0          Muriel, Howell
4  0       Harriet, Phillips
5  0          Belinda, Drake
   1             David, Ford
6  0         Jared, Cummings
   1           Joanna, Burns
   2         Bob, Cunningham
7  0        Keith, Hernandez
   1             Pat, Joseph
8  0    Kristopher, Mckenzie
9  0       Lucille, Thornton
dtype: object
```

Alternative solution:

```
print (np.unique(np.concatenate(df['col2'].str.split(';\s*').values)))
['Belinda, Drake' 'Bob, Cunningham' 'Cecelia, Bass' 'David, Ford'
 'Harriet, Phillips' 'Jared, Cummings' 'Joanna, Burns' 'Julie, Davis'
 'Keith, Hernandez' 'Kristopher, Mckenzie' 'Lucille, Thornton'
 'Muriel, Howell' 'Pat, Joseph' 'Pete, Fitzgerald']
```

EDIT:

For all unique names add `stack` first for `Series` form all columns:

```
print (df.stack().str.split(';\s*', expand=True).stack().unique())

['Pat, Joseph' 'Kristopher, Mckenzie' 'Tony, Hoffman' 'Lucille, Thornton'
 'Miriam, Goodwin' 'Pete, Fitzgerald' 'Cecelia, Bass' 'Julie, Davis'
 'Roxanne, Padilla' 'Muriel, Howell' 'Harriet, Phillips' 'Belinda, Drake'
 'David, Ford' 'Salvador, Reese' 'Jared, Cummings' 'Joanna, Burns'
 'Bob, Cunningham' 'Keith, Hernandez' 'Brenda, Wilkerson']
```

Comment: `df.col2.str.split(';',expand=True).stack().unique()`  this was my solution when I came :(. Arghh should come fast next time

Comment: Thank you for the quick solution. Since it was easy I am going to ask you another one. How can find all the unique names in above data frame?