# How to add a specific character in a list value in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I have a list of values that were pulled from a pandas df column - converted to uppercase - and one of the values contains "" instead of '' for a value. List looks like so:

```
('HUAXIA LIFE INSURANCE CORP', 
"PEOPLE'S BANK OF CHINA (PBOC) - GOVERNMENT SECURITIES DEPOSITORY TRUST & CLEARING CO. LTD.", 'BANCA POPOLARE DI SVILUPPO')
```

I would like to add single quotes in front of the "PEOPLE'S BANK OF CHINA.." value in the list so I can read it in an sql statement. I also need to replace the ' with \ in PEOPLE'S (PEOPLE\S) which is tricky.

I tried using replace

```
str(updated_unique_accts).replace("[",(").replace("]",")").replace("\"","'")
```

but that didn't work - removes the double quotes and replaces them with single quotes. Any ideas for this?

## Desired output

```
('HUAXIA LIFE INSURANCE CORP', 
'"PEOPLE\S BANK OF CHINA (PBOC) - GOVERNMENT SECURITIES DEPOSITORY TRUST & CLEARING CO. LTD."', 'BANCA POPOLARE DI SVILUPPO')
```

Comment: `results = '"' + string + '"'` - Add it to both sides.

Comment: Thank you - can I use that in a .replace() comment or how would I call it to my list? @LarrytheLlama

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47368962/unique-strings-in-a-pandas-dataframe. That may preserve the quotes.

Comment: I guess im still confused how I find all values that have "" and then add single quotes around those values in my list @Carl_M

Comment: updated prompt for more context

Comment: Assuming all results are in a single list: `results = ['"' + s + '"' for s in strings]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering what you have given, I assume you want the final output as a string. With that in consideration, you just had a slight issue with your code. I added one more replace to handle the end condition. Here you go:

```
updated_unique_accts = ('HUAXIA LIFE INSURANCE CORP', 
"PEOPLE'S BANK OF CHINA (PBOC) - GOVERNMENT SECURITIES DEPOSITORY TRUST & CLEARING CO. LTD.", 
'BANCA POPOLARE DI SVILUPPO')
print(str(updated_unique_accts).replace("[","(").replace("]",")").replace(", \"",", '\"").replace("\",","\"',"))
```

OUTPUT:

[image: string substituion]

Comment: Thank you! This did the trick but I think the ' in People's is still throwing off the sql statement. Is there a way to add a '\' where that single quote is? Desired output would look like this: '"PEOPLE\S BANK OF CHINA (PBOC) - GOVERNMENT SECURITIES DEPOSITORY TRUST & CLEARING CO. LTD."',

Comment: updated desired output

Comment: @Dinho You shouldn't simply update your output like that, you should close this and create a new one.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to meet the goal without for loop. The starting output is a tuple as far as python is concerned. Surrounding it with triple quotes makes it a multi-line string. Which can now be processed with .replace().

No for loop is required on the string because of the default replace all.

```
text = '''('HUAXIA LIFE INSURANCE CORP',"PEOPLE'S BANK OF CHINA (PBOC) - GOVERNMENT SECURITIES DEPOSITORY TRUST & CLEARING CO. LTD.",'BANCA POPOLARE DI SVILUPPO')'''
left_replace = text.replace(',"', ',\'"')
right_replace = left_replace.replace('",', '"\',')
print(right_replace)
```

`('HUAXIA LIFE INSURANCE CORP','"PEOPLE'S BANK OF CHINA (PBOC) - GOVERNMENT SECURITIES DEPOSITORY TRUST & CLEARING CO. LTD."','BANCA POPOLARE DI SVILUPPO')`